# Oracle SQL - using column name in one table as query parameter within another

Tags: sql, oracle

Help needed please! Here is the problem:

- I have 2 tables (one transactional, and one lookup/control) as below:

transactional table (A):

```
TXID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, GROUP, DATE, TYPE, AMOUNT, etc.
```

(e.g. `12345, 'SAMPLE TRANSACTION','test','TXGROUP1','FEB.15 2019',500.00, etc.`)

lookup/control table (B):

```
COLID, COLNAME, FLAG
```

(e.g. `1,'NAME', 0; 2,'DATE',1, etc.`)

- In this scenario, entries for COLNAME in table B refer to actual column names in table A (i.e. `B.COLNAME = 'DATE'` refers to A.DATE)

Problem is, I need to write a query that fetches all COLNAME values in table B, and select their corresponding grouped value from table A. For example:

- since `B.COLNAME` contains 'DATE', `select max (DATE) from table A grouping by A.NAME`

What I've tried:

- `select NAME, (SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns where table_name like '%TABLE_A%' AND ROWNUM = 1 GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME) AS COL from TABLE_A;`
- but this only gives me the literal value of the column name - (i.e. `'SAMPLE TRANSACTION', 'DATE'`) - NOT THE DERIVED VALUE as in what I actually need, if I were to run the query manually would be `select NAME, DATE AS COL from TABLE_A;`

and I might expect something like:

`NAME, COL` (e.g. `'SAMPLE TRANSACTION', 'FEB.15 2019'`)

- Ideally am trying to do this only in raw SQL if possible (i.e. no stored procedures, PL/SQL, dynamic, etc....) but... am definitely open to anything that can just make it work.
- input and/or suggestions would be very much greatly appreciated. Environment is Oracle 11g I believe, though I suspect this may not make a huge difference.

Comment: This smells like **dynamic SQL** which you're trying to avoid. It means that you have two options: use dynamic SQL or don't do it at all.

Comment: thank you! pretty much nailed it spot-on...

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to run dynamic SQL in SQL, but the solutions are painful.  The simplest way uses the package `DBMS_XMLGEN` and does not require any additional PL/SQL objects.

The below example works but is unrealistically simple.  A real version would have to deal with many type conversion issues, retrieve other values, etc.

```
--Read a value based on the CONTROL table.
select
    to_number(extractvalue(xml, '/ROWSET/ROW/COL')) COL
from
(
    select xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(v_sql)) xml
    from
    (
        select 'select '||colname||' col from transaction' v_sql
        from control
    )
);

COL
---
  2
```

The results are based on this sample schema:

```
--Sample schema:
create table control
(
    COLID number,
    COLNAME varchar2(4000),
    FLAG number
);
insert into control values(1,'NAME',1);

create table transaction
(
    TXID number,
    NAME varchar2(100),
    DESCRIPTION varchar2(4000),
    the_GROUP varchar2(100),
    the_DATE date,
    TYPE varchar2(100),
    AMOUNT number
);
insert into transaction values(1,2,3,4,sysdate,6,7);
commit;
```

If you have more complicated query needs, for example if you need to return an unknown number of columns, you'll need to install something like my open source program [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4).  That program allows dynamic SQL in SQL, but it requires installing some new objects first.

In practice, this level of dynamic SQL is rarely necessary.  It's usually best to find a simpler way to solve the problem.

Comment: These are definitely good options to keep in one's back pocket (didn't know any of that)... thank you!!